# devexpress multiply value in column

Tags: c#, devexpress

i'm new to devexpress. I need to multiply my column values each by 1000.

I'm trying to achieve it by using this:

```
CertificateTns = { Value = Convert.ToDecimal(__certificate.Tns)*1000 }
```

but it retrives result as always ( for example it was 0,0092 and it retrieves 0,0092 if i multiply or not multiply it by 1000).

Comment: please be more specific, is that a column of PiyotGird ?

Comment: yes. that's PiyotGrid column. A table cell

Comment: refer this link https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q552108

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can check with hardcore value that it gives result as expected. If yes, then add one column with only column to check and compare the actual value and multiply value.

Also check with this link with sample too.

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q432233

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q326687

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q491767

Answer (score 1):

you need to fire`CustomColumnDisplayText` `event` on your `grid` for what you want to achieve, something like :-

```
protected void YourPivotGridName_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Column.FieldName == "Your_ColumnName_to_Be_Formatted")
     e.DisplayText = (Convert.ToInt32(e.Value) * 1000).ToString();
}
```